# Why does Sha1 on Arduino (Little Endian) without conversion to Big Endian work?

Tags: c++, arduino, endianness, sha1

I am in the quite fortunate position to say that my code for a simple SHA1 Hash generator seems to work well. Unfortunately I know that this Arduino Program runs with Little Endianness and the description on the method to generate a hash requires the original message length to be appended as Big Endian integer.

1. This means for the message `char m[] = "Applecake"` I would have 9*8 bits, expressed as a 64-bit unsigned integer that is `0x0000 0000 0000 0048`. That means, stored with Little Endian, the memory would look like this: `0x0048 0000 0000 0000`.
2. As described in [Section 4 of RFC 3174](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3174#section-4) Step c) I have to

   > Obtain the 2-word representation of l, the number of bits in the original message. If l < 2^32 then the first word is all zeroes. Append these two words to the padded message.

   So with my memory as described above, I would have to convert it to Big Endian first and then append the lower 32 bits to the padded message.

The problem is, that if I do convert the Endianness of the length, which I know is Little Endian, I get the wrong padding and therefore the wrong hash.

**Why is my code working without conversion of the Endianness?

Which limitations does my code have concerning the compatibility across different Arduinos, microcontrollers and compilers?**

---

```cpp
// initialize variables
h0 = 0x67452301;
h1 = 0xEFCDAB89;
h2 = 0x98BADCFE;
h3 = 0x10325476;
h4 = 0xC3D2E1F0;

// calculate the number of required cycles and create a blocks array
uint32_t numCycles = ((ml+65)/512)+1;
uint32_t blocks[numCycles*16] = {};

// copy message
uint32_t messageBytes = ml/8 + (ml%8!=0 ? 1 : 0);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < messageBytes; i++) {
    blocks[i/4] |= ((uint32_t) message[i]) << (8*(3-(i%4)));
}

// append the 1 bit
blocks[ml/32] |= ((uint32_t) 0b1) << (31-(ml%32));

// append the 64-bit big endian ml at the end
if (ml < 0x80000000)
    blocks[(numCycles*16)-1] = (uint32_t) ml;
else {
    blocks[(numCycles*16)-2] = (uint32_t) ml;
    blocks[(numCycles*16)-1] = (uint32_t) (ml >> 32);
}

for (uint32_t iCycle = 0; iCycle < numCycles; iCycle++) {
    // initalize locals
    uint32_t w[80] = {};
    uint32_t a = h0, b = h1, c = h2, d = h3, e = h4;
    
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        // convert words to big-endian and copy to 80-elem array
        if (i < 16)
            w[i] = blocks[(iCycle*16)+i];
        else
            w[i] = rotL((w[i-3]^w[i-8]^w[i-14]^w[i-16]), 1);
        
        // run defined formulas
        uint32_t f, k, temp;
        if (i < 20) {
            f = (b & c) | ((~b) & d);
            k = 0x5A827999;
        }
        else if (i < 40) {
            f = b ^ c ^ d;
            k = 0x6ED9EBA1;
        }
        else if (i < 60) {
            f = (b & c) | (b & d) | (c & d);
            k = 0x8F1BBCDC;
        }
        else {
            f = b ^ c ^ d;
            k = 0xCA62C1D6;
        }
        temp = rotL(a, 5) + f + e + k + w[i];
        e = d; d = c; c = rotL(b, 30); b = a; a = temp;
    }
    
    // write back the results
    h0 += a; h1 += b; h2 += c; h3 += d; h4 += e;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// append the 64-bit big endian ml at the end
if (ml < 0x80000000)
    blocks[(numCycles*16)-1] = (uint32_t) ml;
else {
    blocks[(numCycles*16)-2] = (uint32_t) ml;
    blocks[(numCycles*16)-1] = (uint32_t) (ml >> 32);
}
```

This puts the most-significant 32-bit value first and the least-significant 32-bit value second. That's half the reason your code works.

The other half is that while the 32-bit values are in little-endian form, you are reading their *values* on a little-endian platform. That will always give you the correct value. You never try to access the individual bytes of the 32-bit values, so which bytes goes where makes no difference.

Comment: So, even when I do binary shifts over multibyte types, they are handled like they are "Big Endian", meaning "correctly ordered"? That makes a lot of sense to me... Allow me to ask, when do I actually need to worry about Endianness then? Only if I access one of the Bytes directly (like through a Union)?

Comment: @Brainiac When you do binary shifts over multibyte types, you are manipulating their values. How those values are represented has no effect. You only need to worry if you access the bytes directly such as through a union or by casting.